# javascript that produces functioning javascript

Tags: javascript

can you write javascript that produces/writes/etc. functioning javascript?

for example, have a link that has a function tied to it that when clicked produces a functioning javascipt snippet? The snippet could deal with a completely other elements.

For example

Link #1(has the javascript function that produces javascript)       Link #2(does absolutely nothing for now)

Click on link #1(produces javascript snipped that says "when link #2 is clicked document.write('hello')"

Clicking on link #2 now produces "hello" whereas it previously did nothing. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Did you try? What happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can dynamically assign event handlers described in text.

However, dynamic code generation is far more difficult than it sounds unless you're just following basic patters and replacing certain variables. Writing programs that write programs has long been a fascination of the computer industry, and this gave way to [functional programming,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) which can [be done](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter6.html) [in javascript](http://blog.james-carr.org/2009/08/31/functional-programming-in-javascript/).

Comment: ok..i'm decent with php and im trying to get a handle on javascript/jquery. If you are at all interested...what i'm trying to do is display form input fields with jquery's datepicker attached to each one by clicking a link. Every time the user clicks the link a new input field pops up(appends to a div). So i have to make a unique ID for each form field and datepicker function that pertains to that ID(using the timestamp to make unique).

Comment: And i want to also display a delete link for each of these input fields so i'll need to dynamically write a function that removes that particular input field. It's scrambling my brain haha.

Answer (score 0):

Create the input/delete keys on the onClick handler for the datepicker, you can attach date information (or other data) when the input(s) are created.  Now, you should look into `$.delegate()` for how to bind handlers to those inputs created.  `$.delegate` can bind handlers to elements that are not created yet, so when they are created they will fire a handler.  By storing date relevant information in the inputs via `$.data()` or `data-` attributes you will have context aware handlers for dealing with things.

Comment: Read the comments above he is using jQuery's Datepicker

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you could do what you want with the code below.

Not sure why you'd want to do this, though.

> can you write javascript that produces/writes/etc. functioning javascript?

You can do this the way I did it, or by using eval -- though, as many coders have pointed out, eval is evil!

```
<html>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

function initLinks(){
    document.getElementById("link1").addEventListener("click", function(){
        document.getElementById("link2").addEventListener("click", function(){
            document.write("hello");
        }, false);
    }, false);
}
</script>


</head>

<body onload="initLinks()">

<a id="link1">Link 1</a>
<a id="link2">Link 2</a>

</body>

</html>
```